# Swift - Get String From Core Data And Converted In UTF8

Tags: string, core-data, swift

I am trying to get the string for "content" but when I execute the code tha application crash... when I try with `self.content.text = "\(theText)"` it works but I want to encode to UTF8 because I use cyrilic and I get back kind of these `\U0421\U044a\U0434\U044a\U0440\U0436\U0430\U043d\U0438\U0435 \U043d\U0430 \U043f\U0438\U0449\U043e\U0432\U0430` Anyone who can fix the issue?

Here is the code:

```
     let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let theReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity1")
        theReq.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectId == \"\(contentID)\"")
        theReq.predicate = myPredicate
        let executed:AnyObject = context.executeFetchRequest(theReq, error: nil) as Array
        let theText : AnyObject = executed.valueForKey("content")
        self.content.text = theText
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with encoding problems.

- `executeFetchRequest()` returns an *array* of managed objects.
- Applying `valueForKey()` to that array returns an *array* of values.
- Printing the *description* of an array uses `\Unnnn` escape sequences for all
  non-ASCII characters.

So the solution should be simple: Select a single element of the fetched array:

```
let executed = context.executeFetchRequest(theReq, error: nil)[0] as NSManagedObject
let theText = executed.valueForKey("content") as String
self.content.text = theText
```

Of course should also check if the fetch was successful or failed, and if it returned
any object. A more detailed version would look like this:

```
var error : NSError?
let result = context.executeFetchRequest(theReq, error: &error)
if !result  {
    println("fetch failed: \(error)")
} else if result.count == 0 {
    println("nothing found")
} else {
    let obj = result[0] as NSManagedObject
    let theText = obj.valueForKey("timeStamp") as String
    self.content.text = theText
}
```